# Increase the window snapping corner size

Tags: multiple-monitors, window, resize

I often use the window snapping functionality, but I have issues because I use two monitors side by side.

When I want to snap window to the right side of the left monitor, dragging it to the center right of the left monitor doesn't work, because the window moves to the right monitor. Instead, I use the top left corner of the left window.

However, the corner size is minuscule, like 40 pixels out of 1200. I would like to change the top corner size to 200 or 300 pixels, with the top center size reduced to 600-800 pixels. How can I do that? Thanks?